# How Can I display non-fixed number of video files python cv2

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

When Try For One video file . this is working but I need to display the unknown or non-fixed number of video files

I tried os.listdir for loop But I couldnt make it run in a function

I need to send different video paths when First video ends everytime with in order and in infinite loop

```
cap=VideoCapture(path)

while (cap.IsOpened()):
ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
       cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    else:
       print('Not found')
       cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)



    if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
       break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `glob.glob()` to get the list of files you want to open.

Each time one video ends, you should close the VideoCapture and open a new one.

```
from glob import glob

videolist = sorted(glob(r"videoexamplefolder\*.mp4"))  # modify as needed

for video in videolist:

    cap=VideoCapture(video)
    # ...
```

Comment: I did it Thanks I can read the file but Whenever first video ends I coulndt close the cap in right place I guess first video turning again

Comment: check the return of the cap.read() and close the cap when ret is False